# Does SQS kill long running jobs that have Thread.sleep?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have some java code that calls Thread.sleep(100_000) inside a job running in SQS. In production, during the sleep the job is often killed and re-submitted as failed. On dev I can never re-create that. Does SQS in production kill long running jobs?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "a job running in SQS"?

Comment: from my perspective as a developer a job running in SQS is this magical cloud that just runs stuff but I get that it's really some server of ours.

Comment: Correct. Amazon SQS is just a queue that stores messages. It does not "run" any code. Your application will call SQS to store and retrieve messages. The application can run on your own server or on an EC2 server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQS doesn't kill jobs - and I am not sure what you mean by you have code  'running in SQS' - what SQS does do, is to assume your job (which is running someplace other than SQS), has failed if you don't mark it completed within the timeout (Default Visibility Timeout) you set when you setup the queue.

Your job asks SQS for an item to work on (a message to process) - your job is supposed to do that work and then tell SQS that the job is now done (deletemessage). If you don't tell it it is done, SQS makes an assumption for you that the job has failed and puts the message back in the queue for another task to process.

If you need more time to complete the tasks, you can change the default visibility timeout to a higher value if you want.

Comment: Our Default Visibility Timeout was the default 30 seconds, this was changed to 5 mins and now I can call Thread.sleep for 100 seconds without issue.